# Brackets causing Infinite Loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, infinite-loop, brackets

The brackets associated with following the three ***For*** loops cause the function to loop infinitely,

```
void Bubblesort (char ulist[27], char slist[27], int n)
{
int i,j;
char temp;
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    slist[i] = ulist[i];
    for (j=1; j <= n-1 ;j++)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <=n-j;i++)
        {     
            if (slist[i] < slist[i+1])
            {

                temp = slist[i];
                slist[i] = slist[i+1];
                slist[i+1] = temp;
            }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

While without the brackets; the function reaches the end.

```
void Bubblesort (char ulist[27], char slist[27], int n)
{
int i,j;
char temp;
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    slist[i] = ulist[i];
    for (j=1; j <= n-1 ;j++)
        for (i = 1; i <=n-j;i++)
            if (slist[i] < slist[i+1])
            {
                cout << "Step 4";
                temp = slist[i];
                slist[i] = slist[i+1];
                slist[i+1] = temp;
            }



}
```

Would someone be able to explain the reason for this?

Comment: Both your innermost and outermost `for` loops are using the same index variable `i`. For 3 loops, use 3 variables, e.g. `i`, `j`, `k`.

Answer (score 2):

You have changed the semantics of the loop and your indents are misleading.

```
void Bubblesort (char ulist[27], char slist[27], int n)
{
    int i,j;
    char temp;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        slist[i] = ulist[i];
        for (j=1; j <= n-1 ;j++)
            for (i = 1; i <=n-j;i++)
                if (slist[i] < slist[i+1])
                {
                    cout << "Step 4";
                    temp = slist[i];
                    slist[i] = slist[i+1];
                    slist[i+1] = temp;
                }
}
```

should be indented as

```
void Bubblesort (char ulist[27], char slist[27], int n)
{
    int i,j;
    char temp;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        slist[i] = ulist[i];

    for (j=1; j <= n-1 ;j++)
        for (i = 1; i <=n-j;i++)
            if (slist[i] < slist[i+1])
            {
                cout << "Step 4";
                temp = slist[i];
                slist[i] = slist[i+1];
                slist[i+1] = temp;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that without the brackets you don't actually have nested for loops.  consider

```
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    slist[i] = ulist[i];
    for (j=1; j <= n-1 ;j++)
```

Without brackets only the `slist[i] = ...` line executes as  part of the first for loop.  The second for loop executes as a completely separate entity

Once the loops are grouped together though the outer most and inner most loops are using the same index variable.  Their mutual changes to the value conspire to create an infinite loop.  Try using a different index variable for each `for` loop and it will fix the problem.  This works without brackets because the initial error I described causes the first and last loop to not be nested hence they're not manipulating the same value at the same time

Answer (score 0):

The two functions have different algorithms. In the first function you have three nested loops. And the third loop uses the same control variablle 'i' as the first loop. So the loops are infinite because after the third loop i is always equal to 2.

In the second function the first loop is a separate loop that is the other two loops are not nested inside the first loop. So changing control variable 'i' in the third loop does not influence to the first loop.